# SQL Migrate: Split table into two tables with foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, migrate

How to SQL migrate following table into two split tables with foreign key.

#### Current table:

```
  ID  | NAME | VAL1 | VAL2 | VAL3
---------------------------------
1102  | John | 100  | 200  | 300
1103  | Kate | 110  | 210  | 310
```

#### Target tables:

```
  ID  | NAME | VAL_ID          ID | VAL1 | VAL2 | VAL3
----------------------         -----------------------
1102  | John |   1              1 | 100  | 200  | 300
1103  | Kate |   2              2 | 110  | 210  | 310
```

Comment: Any reason for adding VAL_ID and not using ID for both tables?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, yes. After migration same values may be assigned to different users (names). One-to-many relationship.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it make since to generate a distinct set of (val1,val2,val3) and only then generate val_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to generate VAL_ID when ID could be used, which is also the common practice for this use-case.

```
create table base_table as select id,name from src;
alter table  base_table add primary key (id);

create table values_table as select id,val1,val2,val3 from src;
alter table  values_table add primary key (id);
alter table  values_table add foreign key (id) references base_table(id);
```

---

Just to satisfy the OP:

```
create table base_table as select id,name,row_number()over(order by id) as val_id from src;
alter table  base_table add primary key (id);
alter table  base_table add unique (val_id);

create table values_table as select row_number()over(order by id) as id,val1,val2,val3 from src;
alter table  values_table add primary key (id);
alter table  values_table add foreign key (id) references base_table(val_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well . . .

```
create table t1 as 
    select id, name, row_number() over (order by id) as val_id
    from t;

create table t2 as
    select t1.val_id, val1, val2, val3
    from t join
         t1
         on t.name = t1.name;
```

Comment: I doubt the whole concept of generating VAL_ID  but if you do (1) why Joining by name and not by id? (2) why joining in the first place when you can use row_number for both tables?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . `id` doesn't exist until it is created.  I don't follow your comment.

Comment: I'm talking about the original `id` which exist in both `t` and `t1` which you join. We can't trust `name` to be unique, so out of the scope of this sample the JOIN would most likely yield wrong results.